# Draw arrow in WPF

Tags: wpf, winrt-xaml

I wanted to draw the arrow with   element. Is there any way to do that or any tools which autogenerate the path for given shape ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477088/15720206 , I needed arrow which is different than the above post.

reference googled picture:

https://www.google.com/search?q=arrow+head+symbol&safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIN859IN859&sxsrf=ALeKk0306SSwnBsHVElNz35YJeOstlWwsQ:1629698889584&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj94Z27vcbyAhWO_3MBHUp4CMIQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1918&bih=952#imgrc=wv3eg9wV_H09FM

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer: following use of data points will solve:

Data="M 0 10 10 10 10 7.5 15 11 10 14.5 10 12 0 12 Z"